# How can I convert a stringified array field into long columns of integers without repeated fields in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table in this format:

| place | daily_visits |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | [3,12,8,7,18,9,0,3,5,2,3,17,12,3,4,5,3,10,10,9,4,2,5,3,4,13,19,1,3,4,4] |

Both columns are **strings** even though the daily_visits column should be treated as an array of **integers** representing the number of visits on a day of the month (1-31.)

Ideally, I would like the data in this format instead:

| place | visits | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 3 | 1 |
| aaa | 12 | 2 |
| aaa | 8 | 3 |
| aaa | 7 | 4 |

where both `visits` and `date` are integer fields.

I have been able to get it into the format where the visits are stored in repeated fields like this:

| place | visits | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 3 | 1 |
|  | 12 | 2 |
|  | 8 | 3 |
|  | 7 | 4 |

...for which I used this convoluted query:

```
SELECT place, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31] AS date, ARRAY(
  SELECT CAST(integer_element AS INT64)
  FROM `db`, UNNEST(
    JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(daily_visits,'$')
  ) AS integer_element
) AS visits
FROM `db`
```

### Questions:

1. Can my original query be better? I feel like I could use COUNTIF or OFFSET to help number the dates.
2. How can I flatten this so it's not stored in repeated fields?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Consider below simple approach

```
select place, visits, day + 1 as day
from `db`, unnest(daily_visits) visits with offset as day
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  You got me on the right track, but I couldn't use your answer because the `visits` field was stored as a string in the table. I had to convert it to an array first, but your answer with the OFFSET was incredibly helpful.

Comment: consider voting up (at least) - at the same time - i think you can accept it - because it is based on what you provided and the way to adjust it  - extremely simple - just do `unnest(split(daily_visits))` instead of `unnest(daily_visits)`! :o) I ca update my answer if you wish! let m eknow!

Answer (score 0):

With @Mikhail Berlyant's help, I was able to work out this query which extracted the array and also gave me the columns that I needed:

```
SELECT place, 
CAST(visit_integer_array AS INT64) AS visits, 
day + 1 AS day
FROM `db`,  
UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(visits,'$') ) AS visit_integer_array 
WITH OFFSET AS day
```